# jquery validation missing } after property list

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I have this code here:

```
$("#order").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        }
        lastname: {
            required: true
        }
        address: {
            required: true
        }
        telephone: {
            required: true
            digits: true
        }
        email: {
            required: true
            email: true
        }
    }
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        debug = true;
        $(form).ajaxSubmit();
        $("#thanks").show(1000);
        $("#datadiv").hide(500);
    }
});
```

and it throws "missing } after property list" error on firebug on line 4 in this code. And for the love of me, I can't figure out why - because I'm doing everything by jquery documentation.

Comment: can you reformat it so its more readable ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to put commas in between properties of an object literal you are defining.  For example:

```
name: { required: true },  // <-- note the comma
lastname: { required: true },
address: { required: true },
//etc
```

Comment: and also between individual properties of the same object. (see required/digits and required/email.

Comment: except for every last sub-object, otherwise you will get an error on older IE

Comment: thanks! that worked. but there's another thing. submitHandler isn't supposed to submit the form if it's not valid. But with these properties, I can only fill out the name and it is able to submit then. So it looks like it's only checking if name is valid - even though it throws errors for others as well.

Comment: @Jamiec: Yes, I was referring to all object literals and only gave that one as an example.  @donkapone: I'm not familiar enough with jQuery to help there, sorry... I saw the syntax error triggered and knew how to correct that, but this is beyond my current knowledge.

Comment: Ahhhh, I been playing around with this quite a bit and had the same error.... can't believe I missed the commas!!!!!! Thanks @cdhowie