# jQuery validation not validating or submitting

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

This is my 3rd post about this, but I keep making changes, because none of the answers work in full (if the validation works, the submission doesn't, etc.)

```
    $("#order").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit();
            $("#aciu").show(1000);
            $("#duomenysdiv").hide(500);
        },

        rules: {
            vardas: "required",
            pavarde: "required",
            adresas: "required",
            telef: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            vardas: "Koks Jusu vardas?",
            pavarde: "Kokia Jusu pavarde?",
            adresas: "Kur Jus gyvenate?",
            telef: {
                required: "Koks Jusu telefono Nr.?",
                digits: "Telefono numeryje turetu buti tik skaitmenys"
            },
            email: {
                required: "Koks Jusu el. pašto adresas?",
                email: "Iveskite teisinga el. pašto adresa"
            }
        }
    });
```

I am really going crazy here now, but I just can't seem to make it work. I'm struggling with this all day.

With this code, it doesn't validate. It doesn't show the messages, and it lets me submit whenever I wish. When I submit, it hides the div and shows the other div, and places the required data in $_POST, but it doesn't work like it's supposed to.

The submission and the process what it's supposed to do after the submission works perfectly with just

```
$('#order').ajaxForm(function() { 
     $("#aciu").show(1000);
     $("#duomenysdiv").hide(500);
});
```

and no validation.

Comment: stop asking the same questions and change your initial question

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery validation missing } after property list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146732/jquery-validation-missing-after-property-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a submitHnadler insteadof a separate .ajaxForm.

```
    $("#myform").validate({
    //your other code

 submitHandler: function(form) {
 form.submit();
 }
});
```

Comment: that's what I was doing - the first bit of code shows just that. The second bit isn't used simultaneously - I just wanted to show how did it work.

Comment: I saw your original post, you are using $(form).submit. This is not correct.. use as shown above [without $]

Comment: `form.submit()` is redundant and superfluous within the `submitHandler` function.  When the `submitHandler` callback fires, the form is already valid and it will automatically submit.