# multiple grouped radio button validation javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have multiple grouped radio buttons that goes by the name optionRadios1 to 5. i want to validate them via javascript but my validation code isn't working and still continues to submit the form.

here is my code:

```
function submitForm(){

var counter = "<?php echo $count;?>"; //$count is the total number of grouped radio buttons

for(j=1;j<=counter;j++) {   
        var radioname = "optionRadios" + j;

        var elem=document.forms['test-form'].elements[radioname];
        len=elem.length-1;
        chkvalue='';

        for(i=0; i<=len; i++){
            if(elem[i].checked){chkvalue=elem[i].value;}
        }
        if(chkvalue=='') {
            alert('There are still unanswered questions. ' + radioname);
        return false;

        }else {
         $('#test-form').submit();

        }
    }
}
```

this is the form where it should be used:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="test-form">
//lots of codes here

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return submitForm();" id="next">Next</button>


</form>
```

Comment: Want to clarify on "my codes isn't working"?

Comment: sorry, my javascript validation code isn't working

Comment: What does nmean not working ?

Comment: Okay, *how* is it not working? What does it do that it shouldn't, what does it *not* do that it *should*? Can you set up a live demo, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar and illustrate the flaws?

Comment: `still continues to submit the form` How do you prevent it then??? Any error in console? What about debugging it on your side?!

Comment: i've edit my description now. the form should not be submitted as long as a group still doesn't have an answer in it.

Comment: @A.Wolff that's what i am asking.

Comment: Where is your submitForm function called from? Could you post the Javascript/HTML that calls it.

Comment: @TomHart on a form that's calling this function. i will edit it and post the form tag but not the whole form because its so long

Comment: So you are asking how to prevent FORM submission?! If ya, why not clearly asking it???

Comment: @A.Wolff sorry i cannot clearly explain it because i have a hard time writing and speaking in english.

Comment: @ChristianBurgos Ok, looks more clear now, thx for the EDIT. A jsFiddle would help to catch your issue

Comment: @A.Wolff i want to answer my question. i got it working now.. where do i put the answer to my question?

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
$('#test-form').submit(function() {

    var counter = "<?php echo $count;?>"; //$count is the total number of grouped radio buttons

    console.log("Counter: "+counter);
    for(j=1;j<=counter;j++) {   
        var radioname = "optionRadios" + j;
        console.log("RadioName: "+radioname);

        var elem=document.forms['test-form'].elements[radioname];
        len=elem.length-1;
        chkvalue='';

        console.log("Length: "+len);
        for(i=0; i<=len; i++){
            if(elem[i].checked){chkvalue=elem[i].value;}
        }

        console.log("Chkvalue: "+chkvalue);
        if(chkvalue=='') {
            alert('There are still unanswered questions. ' + radioname);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
});
```

Remove the onclick attribute from your button, and look at the values that are being debugged. It will help you see where your code is and isn't working. Try that, and let us know what the console outputs.

Comment: its only returing the name last of the grouped radio buttons and it still submits.

Comment: Could you copy/paste the full output, from Counter: to Chkvalue?

Answer (score 2):

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function(){
var i= 1 ;
var msgError= "";
while($('input[name=optionRadios'+i+']').length ){

    var is_it_ok = false;
    $('input[name=optionRadios'+i+']').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            is_it_ok = true;

        }

    });
    if(!is_it_ok){
        msgError += "Erreur : optionRadios"+i; 
    }
    i++;
}
if(!msgError.length){
       alert("ok");
    return true;
}else{
    alert(msgError);
    return false;
}
});
              });
```

HTML

```
<form name="test-form">
<input type="radio" name="optionRadios1" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="optionRadios1" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" name="optionRadios1" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" name="optionRadios2" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" name="optionRadios2" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" name="optionRadios2" value="1"/>
<input type="button" />
</form>
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/VZHGJ/

Comment: its not working, sorry

Comment: it is still submitting...

Comment: As u already use jquery, I rewrote the all using jquery and updated the jsfiddle

Comment: instead of php/javascript/jquery weird things

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using jQuery validation method? http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: not yet, i don't know how to validate radio buttons via jQuery

Comment: @Lix, I'm not able to put comment if my reputation is not more than 50.... please don't simply downvote...

Comment: @Christian Burgos here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147556/jquery-validation-not-validating-or-submitting

Comment: I gave you an upvote .don't worry nodeffect,be happy

Comment: @nodeffect - there is a reason for that limit - ignoring it is what my actions were based upon.